# BeautifulSoup parsing nested div tags

Tags: beautifulsoup

I need to select the second div from the following structure

```
<div>
A
  **<div>**
    B
      <div>
        C
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
A
  **<div>**
    B
      <div>
        C
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used select to do this:

```
divs = soup.select("div > div")
```

But along with second div and it's content, it is also selecting the third div separately as a part of the list. How to select only divs marked  in my return list.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you could use the following line :

```py
# select all the div tags in page
divs = soup.find_all('div')

for item in divs:      
  inner_div = item.div
```

First you select all the div tags and then you select each one independently.  If you want to translate to another language please visit the Beautiful Soup page for this language.